# Get typedef type and name with libclang?

Tags: c, typedef, libclang

I can get the name and the type of typedefs if they're anonymous structures and the like, but normal typedefs(eg `typedef int size_t`) I can only get `size_t`. How can I get the type "int"?

Comment: How is this question related to Lua?

Comment: I was using libclang with my wrapper made in LuaJIT. I thought I had added that to the post but I guess I forgot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost a year late, but this is the first result that came up when I was searching for this exact question, so here's a hopefully better answer:

In [clang-c/Index.h](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Index_8h.html), the function [clang_getTypedefDeclUnderlyingType](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TYPES.html#ga8de899fc18dc859b6fe3b97309f4fd52) will get the type the typedef was typedef'd *from*, and [clang_getCursorType](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TYPES.html#gaae5702661bb1f2f93038051737de20f4) gets the type it was typedef'd *to*. To clarify, for the line:

`typedef a b;`

`clang_getTypedefDeclUnderlyingType` returns `a`, and `clang_getCursorType` returns `b` (both as a `CXType`).

Comment: A year late while still solving my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot do that. C has no runtime names for types, and in fact when you `typedef` something as `int`, only the compiler cares about type names. The runtime will not be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: Libclang should let you do that. It lets you do other things that you can't determine at runtime. Libclang doesn't compile; it just gives you the AST output in an API form